# Show that $0\cdot m = 0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

If $R$ is a ring with $1$ and $M$ is a left $R$-module, how could I prove that $0_R m = 0_M$? I am using the following axioms

> 1. $(M,+)$ is an abelien group.
> 2. $(r+s)\cdot m = r\cdot m + s\cdot m$ for all $r,s\in R, m\in M$.
> 3. $(r\times s) \cdot m = r\times (s\cdot m)$ for all $r,s\in R, m \in M$.
> 4. $r\cdot(m+n) = r\cdot m + r\cdot n$ for all $r\in R,m,n\in M$
> 5. $1\cdot m = m$ for all $m\in R$

I actually did 
$$0_R m = (r + (-r)) m=rm + (-r)m=rm - rm = 0$$

But then I realized that I made a circular reasoning, because I used this conclusion to show that

$$m + (-1)m=1\cdot m + (-1)\cdot m = (1 + (-1))\cdot m =0 \cdot m = 0$$

, which I used in the first proof.

Comment: Hint: $0m + 0m = (0+0)m = 0m$. Now, $M$ is a group...

Comment: @user251257 Oh oh ouch...

Comment: @user251257 Nothing, it just hurts me that I overlooked that :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Notice that by the ring axioms we have that 
$$0_R=0_R+0_R$$
and by abelian groups we have that
$$a+a=a$$
implies that $a=0_M$ and as such with
$$0_Rm=(0_R+0_R)m=0_Rm+0_Rm\in M$$
and the rest follows.