# Why does $0_R\cdot m=0_M$ and $r\cdot 0_M=0_M$ in a module?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, axioms

According to Wikipedia an R-module is define as:

Suppose that $R$ is a ring and $1_R$ is its multiplicative identity. A left R-module $M$ consists of an abelian group $(M, +)$ and an operation $⋅ : R × M → M$ such that for all $r, s \in R$ and $x, y \in M$, we have:

$$r\cdot (x+y)=r\cdot x+r\cdot y $$
$$(r+s)\cdot x=r\cdot x+s\cdot x $$
$$(rs)\cdot x=r\cdot (s\cdot x) $$ 
$$1_{R}\cdot x=x. $$

My question is why we do not require that $0_R \cdot x = 0_M$ and $r \cdot 0_M = 0_M$. I think these conditions are necessary but I do not see how these follow from the above-given axioms.

Comment: Suppose the product isn't $0$ and say it is $1$, do you see a problem?

Comment: Hi. Please take time to make your titles something informative about the question. I've revised for you this time, but you should take over going forward. Also, search for your question first. Your question is pretty much a duplicate of this one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2014615/29335 I guess it in't *exactly* since you asked two questions instead of one, but still you probably should have been able to see the answer after seeing that one.

Answer (score 2):

Hint :

$0_R \cdot x$
$= (0_R +0_R)\cdot x$

By distributivity in definition of module,

$=0_R \cdot x+0_R \cdot x$.

Can you take it over from here?

Answer (score 0):

$$0x = (0+0)x = 0x + 0x \implies 0x = 0$$
$$r0 =r(0+0) = r0 + r0 \implies r0=0$$